# JavaScript Based Image Input & Keyboard Output

Tags: javascript, python, input, output, artificial-intelligence

this is my first post!

I am working on a project with AI for a game. I am trying to recreate Tetris with Javascript, HTML, and CSS to train an AI to play. After making the game, I would then need to incorporate the AI into it. After it is trained, I want to test the AI against other, real-time players to see how good it is. This is similar to what Code Bullet did, I have attached that video. **My question is, is there any way to have my AI play on a website against other players?** I think this would be possible if I could somehow get input from the site it is playing on, sending it to the AI, and receiving output in the form of simulated presses from the AI. I know this is possible with Python, but I am unfamiliar with that language. If you could help me, that would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

[Code Bullet's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os4DcbpL0Nc)

P.S. Since this is my first post, please let me know if I am doing something wrong/missing something in my post. Thank you again!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bubbly. If you've tried something specific please post a snippet of what exactly didn't work, as of now, your question is still quite broad

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything yet. I am currently brainstorming ways to work on this. Sorry if it is broad. Basically, I am trying to make a game (Tetris), and have an AI play that game. I also want to be able to use that AI on other sites for Tetris, but don't know how to do that.